# Load dSYM symbols in Hopper

Tags: osx, hopper, symbols

Can I load dSYM symbols into Hopper? (I searched extensively in the menus etc. but couldn't find such an option)

Context: I want to see how a program I created using Xcode was compiled into machine code using Hopper to view the machine code. My program is stripped during build but I do have its symbols in a `.dSYM` package.

Comment: Try to give more insight of the context, give some example of what you tried and where you failed.

Comment: @perror: I reformatted my question now to make it more clear what I'm asking and what I tried so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible since [Hopper v3](http://hopperapp.tumblr.com/post/76212665426/hopper-disassembler-v3-at-last-its-almost), under `File > Read Debug Symbols File...`

[image: screenshot]